# Canonical momentum of a 4-vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, differentiation

In a four-vector field theory,
we have a given Lagrangian:
$$\mathscr{L} = C_{1} (\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}) (\partial^{\nu} A^{\mu}) + C_2 (\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}) (\partial^{\mu} A^{\nu}) + C_3 A_{\mu} A^\mu.$$
From that we should compute the canonical momentum:
$$\pi_\nu = \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \partial_0A^\nu}.$$

My question here is:

Can someone please explain me how to take that derivative?
Because I do not understand how to derivate these terms and I do not find an example where this is done for a 4-vector field explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is very homework-like, a full solution should not be presented.

Nevertheless, OP seems to generally have confusion regarding all the 4-vector indices and seems to want a more detailed explanation.

For those reasons, I will show how to compute the derivative in great detail, for just part of the Lagrangian:

> $$\mathscr{L}_1 = C_{1} (\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}) (\partial^{\nu} A^{\mu})$$

Also, in order to avoid confusion between free and summed indices, I will compute
$$
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}_1}{\partial (\partial_0 A^\rho)}\;,
$$
where I am using $\rho$ instead of $\nu$, since $\nu$ is already being used as a summed index in the Lagrangian.

First, rewrite $\mathscr{L}_1$ as:
$$
C_1(\partial_{\nu} A^{\alpha}) g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta} (\partial_{\beta} A^{\mu})
$$
so that all the derivatives have the lower index (just like in the derivative of the Lagrangian we are interested in) and all the fields have upper index.

Then use:
$$
\frac{\partial \partial_\gamma A^{\delta}}{\partial \partial_0 A^{\rho}} = \delta^{0}_\gamma\delta^{\delta}_\rho
$$

And use the product rule to see that:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}_1}{\partial (\partial_0 A^\rho)}
=C_1\frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_0 A^\rho)}\left((\partial_{\nu} A^{\alpha}) g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta} (\partial_{\beta} A^{\mu})\right)
$$
$$
=C_1\left(
\delta^{0}_\nu\delta^{\alpha}_\rho g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}(\partial_{\beta} A^{\mu})
+(\partial_{\nu} A^{\alpha}) g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\delta^{0}_\beta\delta^{\mu}_\rho
\right)
$$
$$
=C_1\left(\partial^0 A_\rho + \partial^0A_\rho\right) = 2C_1\partial^0 A_\rho
$$

So, the final result:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}_1}{\partial (\partial_0 A^\rho)}
=
2C_1\partial^0 A_\rho
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two contributions to $\pi_\nu$, one each from the $C_i$ terms. The first term gives $2\partial^0 A_\nu$, since we can rewrite a term as $C_1\partial_\mu A^\nu \partial^\mu A_\nu$. (This uses a combination of index swapping and index-height changing.) And with a similar treatment of the last term, we arrive at $\pi_\nu =2(C_1\partial^0 A_\nu + C_2\partial_\nu A^0)$.

Comment: Okay thank you, can you please say me how you come to the solution of the first term?
Because I really do not know how to compute these 4 derivatives.
Maybe you can show me the full computation way in steps as a picture or something? That would be really helpful for my understanding :)

Comment: @Armani42 To differentiate $\partial_\mu A^\nu\partial^\mu A_\nu$ with respect to $\partial_0 A^\nu$, just use the project rule. The first factor gives $\delta_\mu^0$, so the contribution is $\partial^0 A_\nu$. The second factor gives $g^{\mu 0}$. giving another copy of the same result. It looks complicated, but it's just a variation on $\partial_x y^2 = 2x\partial_x y$.

Comment: so the first term with C1 I've been written out into a vector and differentiated it. But now I have a problem with the C2 term because there we have $(\partial_{nu} A_{mu})(\partial^{mu} A^{nu})$. So the indices of A and the derivatives are not the same anymore so how to deal with that? In the link I post, you can find a picture of how I calculated the C1 term: https://ibb.co/eMLoRn  So if you look at the last vector, you see what I mean, I now have the $\partial_{mu}$ and then the $\partial^{nu}$ so my question: What has to be done that I can go on computing and come to your result(C2)?

Comment: @Armani42 Rewrite the term as $C_2\partial_\rho A_\mu\partial^\mu A^\rho$, so by the product rule the derivative is $C_2(\delta_\rho^0 \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial^\mu A^\rho+\partial_\rho A_\mu \eta^{\mu 0}\delta^\rho_\nu)$. Simplify that.

Comment: okay, thank you but how can I write that into my 4-vector on the picture? I just want to make it in detail that I really understand what is going on.

Comment: @Armani42 I don't understand your question. I recommend you do the calculation from the start and if you're still confused, revise the question and spell out where you're still stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76309/discussion-between-armani42-and-j-g).